# python shipping and handling calculator using functions

Tags: python

I'm new to programming. I've written 4 basic programs and now I am learning functions. I am trying to make a shipping and handling program that uses functions but I am stuck. Here's the description: Write an application that calculates the total cost for a product including shipping, handling and tax.  This should have 3 functions in addition to main.

1. The first function asks the user to enter the subtotal of their order and returns this information to main.   These values must be validated.  Subtotal must be at least $1 and no more than $9,999.
2. The second function calculates the shipping cost and handling cost then returns this information to main.  Shipping is 10% of the order cost.  For example, the shipping for a $10 order is $1.  Handling is a flat rate of $2 for orders less than $100.  Otherwise, handling is free.
3. The third function calculates sales tax at 6% and returns this information to main.  Sales tax is only based on the subtotal and not on shipping or handling.
4. Main will then display this information on the screen like the sample below.  (Values will have to be passed and returned).

The output should look something like the following:

```
Product Total Information
        Subtotal                         $300.00
        Shipping                           $30.00
        Handling                             $0.00
        Sales tax                          $18.00
        Grand total                     $348.00
```

**Here's what i have so far:
Keep in mind I am completely new to this. Here's my main:**

```
def main():
    subtotal = calc_subtotal
    tax = calc_tax
    shipping = calc_shipping
    handling = calc_handling
    print('subtotal: ')
    print('Shipping: ')
    print('Handling: ')
    print('Sales tax: ')
    print('Grand total: ')
```

**For the subtotal verification i wrote an if/else statement:**

```
def calc_subtotal():
    subtotal = float(input('Enter your subtotal please: '))
    if subtotal >= 1 and subtotal <= 9999:
        print('This is a valid amount')
    else:
        print('Invalid amount')
    return subtotal
```

Now I figure i have to just do something simple to figure the tax amount, such as:
subtotal * .06

And from the way the directions are written it looks like the shipping and handling calculations can be done in the same function?

The part I'm struggling with is how to get the subtotal value to go to the other functions? Like for the tax function, all i need to do is multiply it by .06 but I can't figure out how to call it into that function. I know this is long and you probably have tons of questions that I probably won't be able to answer but if you would like to help I would appreciate it. Thanks for reading.

Here's the updates program code as of 02/23/2017:

```
def main():
    print('This will calculate shipping, handling and taxes on your purchase')
    subtotal = calc_subtotal()
    tax = calc_tax()
    shipping = calc_shipping()
    handling = calc_handling()
    total = calc_total()
    print('subtotal: ', subtotal)
    print('Shipping: ', shipping)
    print('Handling: ', handling)
    print('Sales tax: ', tax)
    print('Grand total: ', total)

def calc_subtotal():
    subtotal = float(input('Enter your subtotal please: '))
    if subtotal >= 1 and subtotal <= 9999:
        print('This is a valid amount')

    else:
        print('Invalid amount')
        return subtotal


def calc_tax():
    subtotal = calc_subtotal()
    tax = subtotal + subtotal * .06
    return tax

def calc_handling():
    subtotal = calc_subtotal()
    if subtotal < 100:
        print('There is a 2 dollar handling fee')
    else:
        print('There is no handling fee')

def calc_shipping():
    subtotal = calc_subtotal()
    shipping = subtotal + subtotal * .10
    print('Your shipping cost is: ', shipping)

def calc_total():
    total = subtotal + shipping + handling + tax



main()
```

Comment: please fix the indentation of your code, so we can be sure of what you've tried.

Comment: ok i think i have it all properly lines up now.

Comment: `subtotal = calc_subtotal` does not call `calc_subtotal`, it makes `subtotal` a reference to the `calc_subtotal` function.  `subtotal = calc_subtotal()` will call make `subtotal` refer to the result returned from `calc_subtotal()`.  You can then define other functions that take that value as a parameter.

Comment: To get the other functions to work do I need to put something in the main? Or should it automatically go through the rest of the functions? When I run it now it loops to the subtotal verification of a number between 1-9999 and displays the print message. Thanks for helping, I'm slowly but surely learning this stuff.

Comment: It's a program, so it will only do what you tell it to do.  What you're describing as 'loops'  isn't a loop, it's just the ordinary flow of control from one function into another (and back).  If you want other functions to be called, you have to write those calls in the order you want them to occur.  If you're new to programming as well as new to python http://www.spronck.net/pythonbook/ may be helpful.  http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/ is also well thought of.

Comment: I'll add onto my original posting with what i have written so far. I thought I had called everything properly but obviously not. I am using "starting out with python" third edition by: Tony Gaddis. I'll def take a look at those sites, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The part I'm struggling with is how to get the subtotal value to go to the other functions?

In the code below I've added a *while* loop so that the user must provide valid input in order to proceed. Rather than *returning* values I've *passed* the `subtotal` and other accumulated values (calculated in each function) to the proceeding function that is called so that the print statements are not repeated.

```
def main():
    print('This will calculate shipping, handling and taxes on your purchase')
    calc_subtotal()   

def calc_subtotal():
    while True:
        subtotal = float(input('Enter your subtotal please: '))
        if subtotal >= 1 and subtotal <= 9999:
            print('This is a valid amount')
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid amount')
            continue
    calc_shipping(subtotal)

def calc_shipping(subtotal):
    shipping_cost = subtotal * .10
    calc_handling(subtotal, shipping_cost)

def calc_handling(subtotal, shipping_cost):
    handling_fee = 0
    if subtotal < 100:
        print('There is a 2 dollar handling fee')
        handling_fee += 2
    else:
        print('There is no handling fee')
    calc_tax(subtotal, shipping_cost, handling_fee)

def calc_tax(subtotal, shipping_cost, handling_fee):
    tax = subtotal * .06
    calc_total(subtotal, shipping_cost, handling_fee, tax)

def calc_total(subtotal, shipping_cost, handling_fee, tax):
    print('\nProduct Total Information')
    print('\tSubtotal: ${}'.format(subtotal))
    print('\tShipping: ${}'.format(shipping_cost))
    print('\tHandling: ${}'.format(handling_fee))
    print('\tSales tax: ${}'.format(tax))
    total = subtotal + shipping_cost + handling_fee + tax
    print('\tGrand total: ${}'.format(total))

main()
```

Output:

```
This will calculate shipping, handling and taxes on your purchase
Enter your subtotal please: 300
This is a valid amount
There is no handling fee

Product Total Information
    Subtotal: $300.0
    Shipping: $30.0
    Handling: $0
    Sales tax: $18.0
    Grand total: $348.0
```

Comment: I don't know why but now my subtotal function isn't asking for the input anymore? When i run it to test i just get the print functions from main to show, nothing else. Any advice? I've cleaned up he code a bit, do you just add it below the original post on this site?

Comment: you just need to click on the edit option to add more code to your question

Comment: ok, thank you. I just added the rest of what I have so far. If you'd like to take a look and give me some feedback I'd appreciate it. Thanks again

Comment: Oh wow! You my friend are awesome! Thank you so much, I'm going to be able to learn alot from this. Thank you, Thank you, Thank you. Oh by the way, thank you :) I'm sure I'll have some questions.